# Problemas Pivotar DataTable con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, datatable, pivot

Puesta en escena:

Con una llamada **Ajax**, ejecuto un **Procedure de la BBDD**, y esta me devuelve una **tabla en formato JSON**

Esta llamada **Ajax** la realiza un código en **JavaScript** y este código vuelve a convertir los datos recibidos a **JSON**

Cuando tengo los datos del **JSON** en el **JavaScript**, paso estos datos a un **DataTable**

[image: DataTable]

Mediante:

```
colorFormat.addGradientRange(min, max, 'black,', '#c3d79b', '#c0504d');
```

Y

```
for (var f in formatters) { formatters[f].formatter.format(dataTable, formatters[f].column); }
```

Consigo ponerle el formato de color a la tabla, **[SOLO LE PONGO FORMATO A LAS COLUMNAS]** y me queda:

[image: DataTable, Columnas formateadas]

Pero me gustaría poder dejarla: **[PONER FORMATO EN LAS FILAS]**

[image: DataTable, Filas formateadas]

DUDA:

Estoy buscando la manera de pivotar la tabla: 
                                                                                 [image: DataTable]

Para dejarla: **[VOLTEAR TABLA SIN AGRUPACIONES, SOLO GIRARLA]**

[image: DataTable Pivotada]

Así poderla formatear las columnas como ya se, me quedara: **[FORMATEAR COLUMNAS DE LA TABLA PIVOTADA]**

[image: DataTable Pivotadad y Formateada]

Y Volverla al “estado” normal **[VOLVER A PIVOTAR LA TABLA ANTERIORMENTE PIVOTADA Y FORMATEADA]**

Y asi conseguiré tener las Filas formateadas como a mi me interesa **[PARA DEJAR LA TABLA QUE ME INTERESA; CON LAS FILAS FORMATEADAS, COMO ME INTERESA]**

[image: DataTable, Filas formateadas]

No consigo ver como Girar y volver al estado normal, el **DATATABLE**, en **JAVASCRIPT** para realizar esta necesidad

*MUCHAS GRACIAS, DE ANTEMANO POR VUESTRA AYUDA*

Comment: No entiendo una cosa, dataTable que es? Framework externo? Gracias

Comment: cierto, perdón:

la dataTable que indico la sacao de: 

var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

y en ese dataTable, es donde cargo los la tabla del SQL, recojida en JSON mediante AJAX

Comment: Buenas, conseguiste arreglar el problema? Como es un framework externo, y menos mal que es de google lo que te permite tener mucha documentación, aqui tienes lo que buscas [https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#google_visualization_charteditor]. simplemente hay que investigar para encontrar si hay lo que tu necesitas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Muchas gracias por la documentación**, luego me la miro mas detenidamente

Realmente no encontré como formatear las filas, es mas en la información que yo encontré ponía que solo se podían formatear las columnas

Por lo que opte por "Girarla" manualmente, formatee las filas(ahora columnas)
y volví a "Girarla" dejándola de la manera "normal" y manteniendo el formateo de las Filas que ahora quedan como me interesa :)

**ej:**

1. Obtengo Tabla 1
2. Giro 90º Derecha Tabla1
3. Formateo las Columnas(lo que antes eran las Filas de la Tabla1) de la Tabla1Girada
4. Giro 90º Izquierda Tabla1Girada

**Resultado:** *Me vuelve a quedar la Tabla1 con las filas (lo que antes eran las Columnas de la Tabla1Girada) **formateadas***

**COMO ME INTERESA**